# nonblocking send()/write() and pending data dealing

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, udp

when the send(or write) buffer is going to be full, let me say, only theres is only 500 bytes space. if I have a NONBLOCKING fd, and do

```
  n = send(fd, buf, 1000,0)
```

here I wll get n<0, and I can get EWOULDBLOCK or EAGAIN error. my questions are:

1 here, the `send` write 500 bytes into the send buffer or 0 bytes to the send buffer?

2 if 500 bytes are sent to the buffer and if the fd is a UDP socket, then the datagram is split into 2 parts?

3 I need to use the `fd` to send many datagrams, if this time the send buffer is full(if there is EWOULDBLOCK or EAGAIN error), I need to make a pending list of datagrams(a FIFO queue). And everytime I want to send some datagram, I will have to check the pending list to see whether it is empty or not. if it is not empty, send the datagram in the pending list first.  It seems to me that this design is a bit troublesome.  And the design is similar to extending the kernel(BTW, is it in the kernel?) send buffer by a userspace pending list. Is there better solution for this?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below only applies to UDP (and only in linux, though others are similar), but that seems to be what you're asking about.

Setting non-blocking mode on a UDP socket is completely irrelevant (for sending) as a send will never block -- it immediately sends the packet, without any buffering.

It IS possible (if the machine is very busy) for there to be a buffer space problem (run out of transient packet buffers for packet processing), but in that case call will return ENOBUFS, regardless of whether the fd is blocking or non-blocking.  This should be extremely rare.

There's a potential problem if you're generating packets faster than the network can take them (fairly easy to do on a fast machine and a 10Mbit ethernet port), in which case the kernel will start dropping the outgoing packets.  Unfortunately there's no easy way to detect when this happens (you can check the interface for TX dropped packets, but that won't tell you which packets were dropped).

Its also possible to have a problem if you use the UDP_CORK socket option, which buffers data written to the socket instead of sending a packet, and only sends a single packet when the CORK option is unset.  In this case, if the buffer grows too big you'll get EMSGSIZE (and again, the NONBLOCKING setting is irrelevant).

Comment: if the UDP datagram is bigger than MTU, what will happen?

Comment: You'll get IP fragmentation.

Comment: it seems IP fragmentation is not working for UDP on some occasions, like his previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652298/is-it-possible-to-send-large-upd-packets-by-setting-ip-header-to-enable-ip-fragm

Comment: Yes, it wasn't the greatest idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about UDP, you are completely off point here - for UDP the value of the `SO_SNDBUF` socket option **puts a limit on the size of a datagram you can send**. In other words, there's no real per-socket send buffer (though data is still queued in the kernel to be sent out by appropriate network controller). You would get `EMSGSIZE` if you try to `send(2)` more in one shot.

For TCP though, you would only get `EWOULDBLOCK` when there's no space in the send buffer at all, i.e. no data has been copied from user to the kernel. Otherwise `sent(2)`'s return value tells you exactly how many bytes have been copyed.

Comment: For AF_INET and AF_INET6 sockets over UDP of type SOCK_DGRAM, the maximum value the SO_SNDBUF option can be set to is 65535 bytes less the IP and UDP header sizes. Anything greater results in an error of [EINVAL]. So SO_SNDBUF is not related to what he asked. He was asking: for example, if SO_SNDBUF=5000. And 4500 is used, so there are only 500 bytes space while he wants to send a UDP packet with 1000 bytes, what will happen.

Comment: You are wrong. It is related. I answered exactly what OP was asking.

Comment: @user138126: the point is, there will never be more than 0 bytes "used" in the buffer prior to calling send (unless the `UDP_CORK` option is on), since any previous packet will have already been sent to the device.