# Understanding how to send larger data chunks over UDP reliably

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, udp

I've used TCP for many things over the years and understand it pretty well. I now have a requirement to use UDP.

Short version: A server allows a small number of clients (5-10) to connect. The server is running a simulation. Clients should be able to update parameters for the simulation and see (a subset) of the simulation results.

In this instance, timing (when the parameters change) is important and the delay between the client requesting a change and it being implemented must be as low as possible.

I've been [doing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2614/Testing-TCP-and-UDP-socket-servers-using-C-and-NET) [a](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92846ccb-fad3-469a-baf7-bb153ce2d82b/simple-udp-example-code?forum=netfxnetcom) [lot](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/virtual-connection-over-udp/) [of](http://www.erg.abdn.ac.uk/~gorry/course/inet-pages/udp.html) [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652298/is-it-possible-to-send-large-udp-packets-by-setting-ip-header-to-enable-ip-fragm) and I'm still not "getting it".

Can someone please confirm/deny my understanding...

- A datagram is stored inside a single packet
- The largest payload I can reliably send is 506 bytes (576 MTU - 60 IP header - 8 UDP header)
- Sending more than that may cause fragmentation
- Fragmentation isn't handled at a lower level and would require me to recombine datagrams (Not sure about this - if it's handled automatically, why do I care about fragmentation?)
- I need to implement my own ACK/Throttling mechanism

So... If I want to send (say) 800 bytes of data from the client to the server, I need to:

- Determine an arbitrary "Protocol" id to be used represented by a Byte(2) that is common between client and server and is used to filter out messages not meant for my app.

#### Client

- Create a random message id
- Split the data into two, add the message id and a global sequence so they can be rejoined at the other end
- Record the data against the sequence id somewhere in memory
- Send them to the server
- If an Ack isn't received in a given timespan (Say RTT * 3), resend that packet.

#### Server

- Inside simulation loop, check (non-blocking) if there is a message on the socket.
- If so, immediately send back a new packet containing an ACK for the sequence Id (actually, to mitigate Ack packet loss, I should Ack the last 30 or so received packets)
- Store the packet in memory until I've received the 2nd half
- Combine the two and process the payload

For messages going in the other direction, I need to do exactly the same in reverse.

I can't help feeling I'm missing something and don't quite understand the implications of a packet fragmenting. Can someone please clarify / point to a better resource?

Comment: It is not handled automatically.  The Socket.DontFragment property is true by default.  You can't get the ICMP message back that tells you that the packet was too large.  Setting it to false requires you solving the problem of getting the packets out of order and still recognizing them correctly.  Reliable UDP has been done many times before, best to use [a library](https://rudp.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the link (and the info in the deleted answer).  That library looks like what I need. If I can avoid reinventing the wheel, I'm happy to do so.

Comment: The UDP header is 28 bytes, not 68. @HansPassant It is handled automatically, by the IP layer, including fragment ordering. The problem with UDP fragmentation is not fragment ordering, it is the absence of retransmission, which implies that lost fragment == lost datagram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - A datagram is stored inside a single packet

Not necessarily.

> - The largest payload I can reliably send is 506 bytes (576 MTU - 60 IP header - 8 UDP header)

Incorrect. The IP header is 20 bytes, not 60, so the total header is 28 bytes. That leaves you 576-28=548, but the number usually bandied around is 534.

> - Sending more than that may cause fragmentation

Yes.

> - Fragmentation isn't handled at a lower level and would require me to recombine datagrams (Not sure about this - if it's handled automatically, why do I care about fragmentation?)

Incorrect. Fragmentation is handled completely at the IP level. The problem with fragmentation in UDP is that there is no ACK/retransmit mechanism for lost fragments, so one lost fragment means the entire datagram is lost. What you see is either an entire UDP datagram or nothing.

> - I need to implement my own ACK/Throttling mechanism

Yes. A simple ACK/retry scheme is given in W.R. Stevens, *Unix Network Programming,* vol I.

Comment: Thanks for the info but re: IP header I've read 20-60 is possible... `Since an IPv4 header may contain a variable number of options, this field specifies the size of the header (this also coincides with the offset to the data). The minimum value for this field is 5 (RFC 791), which is a length of 5×32 = 160 bits = 20 bytes. Being a 4-bit value, the maximum length is 15 words (15×32 bits) or 480 bits = 60 bytes.` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header

Comment: @Basic That's to allow for all the possibilities in TCP. They don't exist in UDP.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. In the end, I was able to get something working very smoothly and your answers pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

> A datagram is stored inside a single packet

No.

> The largest payload I can reliably send is 506 bytes (576 MTU - 60 IP
>   header - 8 UDP header)

'Reliably send' means different things to different levels.

> Sending more than that may cause fragmentation

Economical with the truth.

> Fragmentation isn't handled at a lower level and would require me to
>   recombine datagrams (Not sure about this - if it's handled
>   automatically, why do I care about fragmentation?)

Depends on what level you are at.  At app level, datagrams are either received in their entirety, or not at all.

Sub-questions: Too broad, but it sounds like you should be using TCP instead.

Comment: Apologies if this is too broad - unfortunately, I'm dealing with unknown unknowns. You _may_ be right re: TCP. Fundamentally, what I want is TCP with lower latency. Obviously that's a pipe dream and I need to compromise. Passing state from the server to the client can be lossy with not detrimental effects. From client to server has to arrive "as soon as possible". Would you mind expanding on your answers a little bit to explain the No/Economical responses? Thank you

Comment: @Basic "TCP with lower latency" can only mean "TCP without flow control, ACK/retransmit, sequencing, slow start, congestion avoidance, ...", i.e. all the things you actually need.